# NHibernate join only takes data from the left table

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I want to performe a join between a view and a table with NHibernate. The columns COL1 and COL2 belong to MY_VIEW, the columns COL3 and COL4 belong to MY_TABLE. Both of them have an ID column, and I want to join them based on it. I am using the following code but the query resulting from it selects all the columns from MY_VIEW, so it fails.

```
Table("MY_VIEW");
ID(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned().Column("ID");
Map(x => x.Col1).Column("COL1");
Map(x => x.Col2).Column("COL2");

Join("MY_TABLE"", m => {
    m.Optional();
    m.KeyColumn("ID");
    Map(x => x.Col3).Column("COL3");
    Map(x => x.Col4).Column("COL4");
});
```

The query looks like this:

```
select v.COL1, v.COL2, v.COL3, v.COL4 
from MY_VIEW v left outer join MY_TABLE t 
on v.ID = t.ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this small change:

```
Join("MY_TABLE"", m => {
    ...
    m.Map(x => x.Col3).Column("COL3");
    m.Map(x => x.Col4).Column("COL4");
});
```